# Replacing a fragment does not replace the previous fragment entirely. Why so?

Tags: android-fragments, android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm implementing a "fragments-101" program, where-in I replace a fragment when its corresponding button is clicked. However, the below thing happens:

[image: On launching the app]

[image: On clicking "Launch Fragment 1"]

[image: On clicking "Launch Fragment 2"]

Why does this happen? Why is the initial fragment not replaced completely?
MainActivity and both fragment xml files use LinearLayout. I searched here about the problem, and found that the replace() method can sometimes be buggy, so I tried using add(), but to no avail. There is no special code in the fragments, it's a simple hello-world-type fragment program.

I'm using Android Lollipop version in the AVD as well as the targetSDK, with minSDK version corresponding to Android 4.0.3, in Android Studio 1.0.2. Can this be something related to Android Lollipop?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.fragmenttest;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    FragmentManager fm;
    FragmentTransaction ft;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void launchFragment(View v)
    {
        Fragment frag;

        if(v == findViewById(R.id.btnFrag2))
        {
            frag = new FragmentTwo();
        }
        else
        {
            frag = new FragmentOne();
        }

        fm = this.getFragmentManager();
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.myFrag,frag);
        ft.commit();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

layout_frag1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ffff">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 1."
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

layout_frag2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffff00">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 2."
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="348dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Launch Fragment 2"
        android:id="@+id/btnFrag2"
        android:onClick="launchFragment"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="355dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Launch Fragment 1"
        android:id="@+id/btnFrag1"
        android:onClick="launchFragment"/>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:name="com.example.fragmenttest.FragmentTwo"
        android:id="@+id/myFrag"
        tools:layout="@layout/layout_frag2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use a ViewGroup such as FrameLayout as a container to attach Fragment to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Fragments` that are inflated directly from xml layout with `<fragment/>` tag cannot be replaced.

You should have an empty `FrameLayout` inside your `xml` layout. And you should add, remove, replace all your `Fragments` programmatically into that `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Using a FrameLayout worked. Though I'm still not convinced as to why a directly inflated fragment cannot be replaced entirely. Any specific reason for it?

Comment: I think there is not but it is just how Android team implemented it. They decided to have it like this. I now it is frustrating.

Comment: Seems I'll have to make-do. Well, what the heck! Thanks mate!!