# Fragment not getting replaced on click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an `Activity` which consists of a `Fragment`. The `Fragment` has two ViewGroups (LinearLayouts),which I want to use like buttons to change the layout of that very `Fragment`.

I am facing two problems in this:
 1. The two LinearLayouts don't give any visual touch-feedback (ripple animation) even when `clickable="true"` and `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` is set.
 2. The `Fragment` doesn't get replaced by a new `Fragment` even though `onClickListener` for the two `LinearLayout` works (checked using a `Snackbar`).
 3. In the statement `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_linearlayout,sb_qa_defaultFragment).commit();`, I read on SO that the first argument of add should not be the id of the `fragment` itself but the `container` of the `fragment`. Is it true ? Because I got the same behaviour setting id of the `fragment` or its `container` as the first argument.

**MainActivity**

```
public class sb_question extends AppCompatActivity{

    private LinearLayout typeAnswerLL, recordAnswerLL ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sb_question_new);

        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        SB_QA_defaultFragment sb_qa_defaultFragment = new SB_QA_defaultFragment();
        final SB_TextAnswerFragment sb_textAnswerFragment = new SB_TextAnswerFragment();


        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_linearlayout,sb_qa_defaultFragment).commit();

        typeAnswerLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.type_answer_linearlayout);
        typeAnswerLL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                THIS STATEMENT BELOW DOESN'T WORK AND DOES NOTHING
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_linearlayout, sb_textAnswerFragment).commit();
//                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Type Answer", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
//                snackbar.show();
            }
        });

        recordAnswerLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.record_answer_linearlayout);
        recordAnswerLL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Record Answer", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        });

    }
```

**Layout of MainActivity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/sb_ques_toolbar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/sb_ques_toolbar_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <TextView
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:id="@+id/sb_ques_text"
                android:minHeight="70dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_linearlayout"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/text_record_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="com.example.yankee.cw.SB_QA_defaultFragment">
            </fragment>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:text="Save &amp; Exit"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:text="Skip Question"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If it helps, here is the XML Layout of the `Fragment` I set as default when the `Activity` is launched [sb_qa_default_layout.xml](https://gist.github.com/gamebusterz/6486078d40450bb1011df973961008ee) and its [Java code](https://gist.github.com/gamebusterz/454a11298822404fb5c897ae2d0bc41a)
Same for the `Fragment` which will replace the default `Fragment` on clicking the `LinearLayout` on the default `Fragment`. [Layout](https://gist.github.com/gamebusterz/d6ef5b77d84a58483ecf61351d2481d9) and its [Java Code](https://gist.github.com/gamebusterz/fdb6273ffcdb342579774da981d5a2f9)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the solution for your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632443/replacing-a-fragment-does-not-replace-the-previous-fragment-entirely-why-so

Comment: @MikeM. So, you mean to dynamically change fragments, I will have to add fragments at runtime and then replace it ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @MikeM. Any help on the 1st and 3rd questions please ?

Comment: For #3, yes, the ID is for the `ViewGroup` that will hold the `Fragment`; it's container. #1 is a completely different question.

Comment: @MikeM. Sure, thanks !!

Comment: Check by changing fragment_linearlayout to FrameLayout.

Comment: @ReadyAndroid Thank you. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ExampleFragments fragment = new ExampleFragments();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question since it is exactly what the OP did, only here is on multiple lines of code